# ActiveCollab - How to make an ajax call from a custom module on page load

Tags: javascript, ajax, load, activecollab

I'm trying to initiate an ajax call on project brief page by adding a javascript file.I need to display some extra information along with existing project brief information. I included a javascript file in a custom module and followed the procedure explained below. Can you correct me If I'm missing anything here.

I used $.ajax({}) to call the ajax request and my code is like this

```
    $.ajax(
    {
         type: "post",
         url: "index.php?path_info=projectfieldsextra",
         'data' : { 'client_value' : 178}, 
         success: function(el)
         {
               alert(el);
               return false;
            //$("#project").html(el);
           }
    });
```

In controller I created a function get_project_information() and in module definition class I created a route like this

```
     Router::map('projectfieldsextra', 'projectfieldsextra', array('controller' => 'project_fields', 'action' => 'get_project_information'));
```

But while makinf call , it is giving me an error like this -

```
   Call to a member function isInlineCall() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/activecollab/activecollab/4.0.13/angie/frameworks/environment/controllers/FwApplicationController.class.php on line 211
```

Could anyone help me out in this ?

Thanks in advance
Jayesh

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that your custom controller (`ProjectFieldsController`) is not properly set up (it is not properly accepting construction parameters and transferring them to the parent class). If you are overriding controller's constructor, you should do it like this:

```
/**
 * Controller constructor
 *
 * @param Request $parent
 * @param mixed $context
 */
function __construct($parent, $context = null) {
  parent::__construct($parent, $context);

  // Your code
}
```

Note that there are other problems with your code, but they are not part of the question, so I will mention them just briefly:

1. Don't hack the system module. That's a recipe for upgrade problems. Write your own module that hooks into the system via supported events instead.
2. System convention is to use underscore notation for various system names, including route names. `show_project_info` is much more readable than `showprojectinfo`. This is not an error, but you will get along with the framework much easier if you follow the existing naming conventions.